# How to store CGRect and other things in core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios4

I'm having a few teething problems with coredata, but feel it would clear things up for me greatly if someone could explain some simple cases to me.

I want to put my model into coredata, and at a most simple case take advantage of undo/redo. Thing is, all the examples I see tend to store either strings or integers. What if I have a class as follows that I wanted to implement in core data (a made up example):

```
@interface Badge : NSObject {

NSString *textForBadge;
int      badgeValue;
UIColor  *color;
CGRect    rect;
NSMutableArray *awards; // this would be a list of 'Category' - another custom class
}
```

*These are all made up on the spot, but each highlight a confusion*

As I see it, I would open the .xcdatamodel and add a new Entity caled 'Badge', which would be an `NSManagedObject`. I then add a property for `textForBadge` of type `String`. So far so good. I do somthing similar for badgeValue, but then come to the `UIColor` and `CGRect` and I'm a bit stumped, since there isn't a property for those. Am I supposed to create an entity to represent each (i.e a `Rect` entity that has four properties `x,y,w,h`) that are ints? Then populate a CGRect with these ints each time? Ditto for the UIColor?

Finally, I come to my list of `awards`. If these are a list of pointers to a number of objects representing an award they might contain an image, a colour, text etc. I assume that `award` would again be an entity I have to design and rather than `Badge` storing an array I would have a 1 to many relationship from it to the `Award` class.

Am I getting any of this right, or going in the compete opposite direction? All the examples I see operate on vanilla objects like String or int so want to make sure I have this right in my head before implementing a bunch of stuff.

Kind regards,

Bryn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the relevant documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html but essentially, you have to provide a way for Core Data to translate between your non-standard properties and the kinds of things it can store.  There are two ways to do it.  Either use transformable attributes and value transformers, or use transient properties and do the conversion only when the managed object context is going to be saved.

I think in most cases, what you describe (defining custom entities to store the components of something like a CGRect) is overkill.

Comment: The link you referenced here is dead. @AndrewMadsen

Answer (score 24):

Specifically regarding `CGRect` you can use `NSStringFromCGRect` store a `CGRect` as `NSString`.
Then use `CGRectFromString` to convert it back:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake( 5, 5, 40, 30 );
NSString* rectAsString = NSStringFromCGRect( rect );
CGRect original = CGRectFromString( rectAsString );
```

This allows you to easily store it in a NSManagedObject.
You can then add a custom accessor in your implementation to convert it:

```
- (CGRect)realRect {
    return CGRectFromString( self.rectAsString );
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Storing UIColor objects and structures like CGRect in Core Data is fairly easy (this may be new since the OP asked about it):

Define the objects as Transformable in your model:

[image: snapshot of Core Data model]

In the NSManagedObject classes define and use UIColor objects normally:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *foreground;

textView.textColor = element.foreground;
```

Wrap CGRect structures in an NSValue object:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSValue *imageRect;

CGRect imageRect = [self.imageRect CGRectValue];
imageRect.size.width = 100;
self.imageRect = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:imageRect];
```

Comment: This is the recommended way to do this sort of stuff

Answer (score 10):

You have to be careful if you use the NSStringFromCGRect serialization suggested by aegzorz. This doesn't work reliably for big numbers that get abbreviated in the NSString representation.

For example, this code

```
CGRect test1 = CGRectMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX);
NSString* test1Str = NSStringFromCGRect(test1);
CGRect test2 = CGRectFromString(test1Str);
NSLog(@"test1: %f %f %f %f", test1.origin.x - CGFLOAT_MAX, test1.origin.y - CGFLOAT_MAX, test1.size.width - CGFLOAT_MAX, test1.size.height - CGFLOAT_MAX);
NSLog(@"test2: %f %f %f %f", test2.origin.x - CGFLOAT_MAX, test2.origin.y - CGFLOAT_MAX, test2.size.width - CGFLOAT_MAX, test2.size.height - CGFLOAT_MAX);
```

will output

```
test1: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
test2: -344800963262078397207103271862272.000000 -344800963262078397207103271862272.000000 -344800963262078397207103271862272.000000 -344800963262078397207103271862272.000000
```

In my opinion it's better to store the four values separately.