# Fetching from Core Data with swift causes crash because I receive other type of object

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am fetching objects from Core Data with Swift and instead of having a "Themes" object I get NSManagedOBject

**Class Enity:**

[image]

**Class: Themes.swift**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

    @objc(Themes)
    class Themes: NSManagedObject {

    }
```

**class: Themes+CoreDataProperties.swift**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Themes {

    @NSManaged var themeName: String?
    @NSManaged var topBarColors: NSData?
    @NSManaged var bottomBarColors: NSData?
    @NSManaged var bottomBarIconsColor_default: NSData?
    @NSManaged var bottomBarIconsColor_selected: NSData?
    @NSManaged var background_image: NSData?
    @NSManaged var isBackgroundBlured: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var font_phoneTitle: NSData?
    @NSManaged var font_name: NSData?
    @NSManaged var font_phoneNumber: NSData?
    @NSManaged var font_barButtons: NSData?
    @NSManaged var font_organization: NSData?
    @NSManaged var font_initiala: NSData?
    @NSManaged var isPredefined: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var isRandomInitialBackgroundColor: NSNumber?
    ///0 gratis, 1 cu bani etc
    @NSManaged var priceTier: NSNumber?

}
```

**Fetching:**

```
func fetchThemes() {
    let moc = AppDelegate().managedObjectContext
    let personFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Themes")

    do {
        let fetchedPerson = try moc.executeFetchRequest(personFetch) as! [Themes]
        print("fetched: \(fetchedPerson)")
        arr_themes = fetchedPerson

    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to fetch person: \(error)")
    }
}
```

**And I get this and crash:**

[image]

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Error message from crash log?

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your reply. Updated question

Comment: @TommieC. Found the problem. Had nothing to do with coredata. When I was declaring variable I was alocating it, and when setting it caused crash. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Themes is an NSManagedObject subclass. It's not clear why you are using setters and getters in this way, You don't need to do that at all. The NSManagedObject will never be assigned as a color in any case. You might want to have a look at the following [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835093/storing-uicolor-object-in-core-data/23837235#23837235). You can also search for related questions on the right-hand side of that answer so that you can get a good idea of how to store, retrieve the UIColor on Core Data. Google will produce detailed code for using UIColor with Core Data.

The gist of this is:

1. Create an attribute to store the color and mark as Transformable
2. Generate the NSManagedObject subclass for the Themes object
3. Change the generated type from NSObject? to UIColor?
4. Add import UIKit to top of the Themes subclass file

Once you have the class created correctly you can do the following in your code (and Core Data will managed UIColor storage automatically).

```
//Themes class after regeneration when you set the attribute to Transformable in the Core Data Model Editor and regenerate
@NSManaged var backgroundColor: NSObject?

//after you update to support adding a UIColor
import UIKit
//...
@NSManaged var backgroundColor: UIColor?

//create your new Themes object
var colorObject:Themes = //...

//Set the backgroundColor attribute 
colorObject.backgroundColor = UIColor().redColor()
```