# Coredata relationship, save Dictionary

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a CoreData object called `Game` and it has a relationship called `playedList`. I wanted it to hold a dictionary of data. Things I'm not sure about.

1) Does a relationship have to be an `NSSet`?
2) How would I save a Dictionary [String: Int] or [Player:Int] to that relationship?

I had tried to change the relationship to `NSData` and use

```
game.playedList = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(myDictionary, options: [])
    } catch {
        print("JSON serialization failed:  \(error)")
    }
```

> Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship:

I'm a little unsure on this as it's my first time with CoreData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CoreData entity's relationship must be to one or more other CoreData entities. You cannot define a relationship between an Entity and a non-CoreData object like a Dictionary.

You can define a new Entity with attributes to store each key in this dictionary (if they are predictable).

Alternately you could store your Dictionary as a Data attribute using a ValueTransformer (see [Storing UIColor object in Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835093/storing-uicolor-object-in-core-data/23837235) and similar)

Comment: Ok, so in my situation, what do you think is the best way to store a dictionary of who played and the time they played? From what you're saying, should I add a new attribute to my game entity and set it as Transformable, then save it as NSData?

Comment: If you're storing predictable data then it sounds like you're missing an Entity type. Perhaps in your case that's a `Replay` or `GameRecord` which contains `duration` and `playerName` attributes or even has another relation to some `Player` entity.

Comment: Well I have a `Game` entity, that game belongs to a `Team`, `Players` belong to `Team`. I want a way to store, which players, played in each game and how much they played. I know I could have an `NSSet` of players who played, which I currently do have. But not sure the best way to save how many minutes each of those players played? (Bearing in mind that some players might not play in every game if injured etc). What do you think?

Comment: Sounds like you might have a `roster` or `lineup` relation from your `Game`. Each element of that relation could then store time played that game and have a relation to a `Player`. Alternately a more complicated model might compose a "game" from a series of "plays" each of which has a duration and contains many players, in that case you could then compute the total time player per player as the sum of the plays in a given game in which they participated.