# How to store type Color from SwiftUI into CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I tried to use Transformable type in core data but the Color can not be cast into NSObject. What should I do if I want to store the Color information?

Comment: I believe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835093/storing-uicolor-object-in-core-data

Comment: @DevKyle Thanks and I tried this way before, but the Color type in SwiftUI can not be cast to NSData

Comment: I found excellent article on this topic. https://yozy.net/2020/10/storing-colors-in-core-datathe-whole-story/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Transformable`, although it has to be stored as `UIColor` and not `Color`:

> The `withRootObject` is the colour you want to save.

Also keep in mind that `myColour` should be of type `Data`:

`@NSManaged public var myColour: Data?`

Then you can archive the data like the following:

```
do {
    try obj.myColour = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: UIColor.blue, requiringSecureCoding: false)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Retrieve it using:

```
func getColour(data: Data) -> Color {
    do {
        return try Color(NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: UIColor.self, from: data)!)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    return Color.clear
}
```

Usage:

```
Text("This is some blue text.") // we saved it as UIColor.blue earlier.
    .foregroundColor(self.getColour(data: self.data.myColour!))
```